# Why is BigDecimal's precision not accurate enough?

Tags: java

Code:

```
BigDecimal test = new BigDecimal(3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330530548820466521384146951941511609433057270365759591953092186117381932611793105118548074462379962749567351885752724891227938183011949129833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132000568127145263560827785771342757789609173637178721468440901224953430146549585371050792279689258923542019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303598253490428755468731159562863882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927876611195909216420199);
System.out.println(test.toPlainString());
```

Here is the output:

```
3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
```

I debugged it and `test` has a value of `3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875` in memory too. This is quite intriguing because only the first part is right: `3.141592653589793`.

Comment: I realized that the issue is that the number literal is being treated as a double. The solution is to wrap the number in quotation marks to pass a string to the constructor of BigDecimal. I will leave this question for anyone in the future reading it.

Comment: Because your 3.14... literal is initially encoded as a `double`.

Comment: @user2950075 That's right, I was just about to post that as an answer.

Comment: So close this question then.

Comment: How would I close it?

Comment: -1 for not reading the API docs **before** using SO.

Answer (score 5):

Your `3.1415...` is a double literal, it gets truncated to double precision by the compiler before the `BigDecimal` even sees it. Put quotes around it and pass it as a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
new BigDecimal(double)
```

constructor will get the imprecision of `double`.

Try using the `String` based constructor instead:

```
new BigDecimal("3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330530548820466521384146951941511609433057270365759591953092186117381932611793105118548074462379962749567351885752724891227938183011949129833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132000568127145263560827785771342757789609173637178721468440901224953430146549585371050792279689258923542019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303598253490428755468731159562863882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927876611195909216420199")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with quotes around the value in the constructor:

```
BigDecimal test = new BigDecimal("3.14159265358979323846264 .... ");
```

As it is at the moment you are really adding a lower precision Java `double` value, not the full precision number

Answer (score 0):

You are building a `BigDecimal` object by using [the constructor which takes a double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29). Thus, Java will convert your number to `double` before building the `BigDecimal` object.

Javadoc says:

> The results of this constructor **can be somewhat unpredictable**. One might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625.

Try using [another constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) which takes a `String` for example.

Answer (score 0):

BigDecimal is accurate enough. However, the number you provided is being converted to the not accurate int or long. Just because you made a long number, does not mean it was taken with that precision:

```
BigDecimal test1 = new BigDecimal(3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330530548820466521384146951941511609433057270365759591953092186117381932611793105118548074462379962749567351885752724891227938183011949129833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132000568127145263560827785771342757789609173637178721468440901224953430146549585371050792279689258923542019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303598253490428755468731159562863882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927876611195909216420199);
System.out.println(test1.toPlainString());
```

The output is:

```
3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
```

Try this instead, enclose the input in quotes so that the full precision is captured and it does not get converted by the compiler to a int or long:

```
BigDecimal test2 = new BigDecimal("3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330530548820466521384146951941511609433057270365759591953092186117381932611793105118548074462379962749567351885752724891227938183011949129833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132000568127145263560827785771342757789609173637178721468440901224953430146549585371050792279689258923542019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303598253490428755468731159562863882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927876611195909216420199");
System.out.println(test2.toPlainString());
```

The, the output of test2 will be the full precision:

```
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330530548820466521384146951941511609433057270365759591953092186117381932611793105118548074462379962749567351885752724891227938183011949129833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132000568127145263560827785771342757789609173637178721468440901224953430146549585371050792279689258923542019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303598253490428755468731159562863882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927876611195909216420199
```